# Prove that $\max\{a+b,c+d\} \leq \max\{a,c\} + \max\{b,d\}$

Tags: real-numbers

I've got the number $\max\{a,b\}$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R$

$\max\{a,b\}=a, a\geq b$ or $\max\{a,b\}=b, a<b$
We can see that $\max\{a,b\}\leq c$ only if $a\leq c$ and $b\leq c$
Now, if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ , prove that $\max\{a+b,c+d\} \leq \max\{a,c\} + \max\{b,d\}$

I am really stuck here, I need this for my University.

Comment: I've got the number max{a,b} and a,b∈R

max{a,b}=a, a≥b or max{a,b}=b, a<b
We can see that max{a,b}≤c only if a≤c and b≤c
Now, if a,b,c,d ∈ R , prove that max{a+b,c+d} ≤ max{a,c} + max{b,d}

I am really stuck here, I need this for my University.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that $a\leq \max\{a,c\}$ and $b\leq \max\{b,d\}$ which means  that $$a+b\leq \max\{a,c\}+\max\{b,d\}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Can you please complete this proof?

Comment: @agdhruv, do the same for $c+d$. Then you have $a+b$ and $c+d$ are both bounded by $\max\{a,c\}+\max\{b,d\}$, so  $\max\{a+b,c+d\}\leq \max\{a,c\}+\max\{b,d\}$.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to consider $\max \{x,y\} = \frac{x + y + |x-y|}{2}$ and use the triangle inequality.